# Calling DeleteAsync Method

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I am using `System.Net.Http` in windows phone application to delete item from the list by calling WebAPI service by using method of `DeleteAsync(Uri)`

but I want to use it like PUT or POST method
like this

```
client.PostAsync("api/WorkRegs", new StringContent(jsonarr.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "text/json"));
```

because I want to send the list along with it to the service

Comment: Does the list you want to delete items from reside on Webserver ?

Comment: Yes 
basically first i want to delete it from mobile then i want to delete it from the SQL Server.